# Angular translation extraction fails

Tags: angular, localization, angular-localize

I am using Angular 10 in one of my projects, I am not able to use localization in the project.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. First of all I added the localization package using `ng add @angular/localize`
2. Then I added the `i18n` attribute in one of my HTML tags.
3. Now I am trying to create a translation file using `ng xi18n`

But I am getting the following error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/extract-i18n/ivy-extract-loader.js):     
Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/sourcemaps'
Require stack:
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\localize\src\tools\src\extract\extraction.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\ivy-extract-loader.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\xi18n-impl.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\Awais Ashraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\Awais Ashraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1140:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
    at F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\localize\src\tools\src\extract\extraction.js:14:24
    at F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\localize\src\tools\src\extract\extraction.js:3:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\localize\src\tools\src\extract\extraction.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1140:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\ivy-extract-loader.js:10:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)

Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/extract-i18n/ivy-extract-loader.js):
Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/sourcemaps'
Require stack:
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\localize\src\tools\src\extract\extraction.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\ivy-extract-loader.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\xi18n-impl.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\Awais Ashraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\Awais Ashraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1140:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
    at F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\localize\src\tools\src\extract\extraction.js:14:24
    at F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\localize\src\tools\src\extract\extraction.js:3:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\localize\src\tools\src\extract\extraction.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1140:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\ivy-extract-loader.js:10:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)

Error: ./src/main.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/extract-i18n/ivy-extract-loader.js):
Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/sourcemaps'
Require stack:
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\localize\src\tools\src\extract\extraction.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\ivy-extract-loader.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\index.js
[91m- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\xi18n-impl.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\Awais Ashraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\Awais Ashraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1140:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
    at F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\localize\src\tools\src\extract\extraction.js:14:24
    at F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\localize\src\tools\src\extract\extraction.js:3:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\localize\src\tools\src\extract\extraction.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1140:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\ivy-extract-loader.js:10:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)

Error: ./src/polyfills.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/extract-i18n/ivy-extract-loader.js):
Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/sourcemaps'
Require stack:
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\localize\src\tools\src\extract\extraction.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\ivy-extract-loader.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\xi18n-impl.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\Awais Ashraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\Awais Ashraf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1140:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
    at F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\localize\src\tools\src\extract\extraction.js:14:24
    at F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\localize\src\tools\src\extract\extraction.js:3:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular\localize\src\tools\src\extract\extraction.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1140:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Work\aiFeed\publishers-portal\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\extract-i18n\ivy-extract-loader.js:10:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
```

I have been trying to find the solution for quite some time now, any quick help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the documentation I am following: https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Comment: Do you have @angular/compiler-cli in your devDependencies and does its version match your Angular version? 
If you can, try updating to a newer Angular version.

Comment: @MichaelKarén I have to change the version of my devkit-builder from 0.1100.1 to 0.1000.5 and remove a timezone package that I was not using anymore and it solved the issue for me.